# map = with space in vim with inoremap

Tags: vim

First, I must admit, I am doing to much for simply typing a spacebar, the easiest key to press. But this is a learning experience. So kindly help me solve the problem.

The problem is, I want when I type `" ="` in vim, it transforms to `" = "`, so, say, `"k =" -> "k = "`
So I have done a mapping:

```
inoremap <expr> = getline(".")[col(".")-2] =~ '[[:blank:])]' ? "= " : "="
```

So good so far.
But, problem arises when I need to have `" == "`. With the above map, I will always end up `" = = "`, which is not I want.

I tried to map it like:

```
inoremap <space>=<space>= <space>==<space>
```

which is also working fine, except an irritating consequence that, vim will always wait for the next key whenever the `<space>` is pressed.

As from [vim_space_in_lhs](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#map_space_in_lhs) I also tried

```
inoremap <C-V><C-V><space>=<C-V><C-V><space>= <space>==<space>
```

But this is killing the mapping completely, i.e. `"k ="` remains like that, rather than `"k = "`, from the first map.

I know, I can solve all the problem with typing single space, but I want to solve it.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
inoremap <expr> = getline(".")[col(".")-3] == '=' ? "<bs>= " : getline(".")[col(".")-2] =~ '\s' ? "= " : "="
```

Should do it

EDIT:

Given the new *requirements*, here is a function and the related mappings that'll do the work.

Note: This is meant to be defined in ftplugins: you don't want such mappings on `<` to be triggered in xml-like languages. You may also have to define several functions, or a second parameter on the function to handle more precisely the behaviour of these mappings.

```
function! s:InsertExpr(char)
  let line = getline('.')
  let col  = col('.')
  return 
        \   line[col-3] =~ '[=<>!~]' ? "\<bs>".a:char." "
        \ : line[col-2] =~ '\s\+'    ? a:char." "
        \ :                            a:char
endfunction
inoremap <buffer> <expr> = <sid>InsertExpr('=')
inoremap <buffer> <expr> < <sid>InsertExpr('<')
inoremap <buffer> <expr> > <sid>InsertExpr('>')
```

Comment: Thanks, its working, but goes well over my head. Can you kindly find time to explain? 
Firstly, in the first getline, what is `==` is this a regex? or comparison? I am trying other combinations to check myself, but will be faster if you kindly explain

Comment: to be more pinpoint, I tried the same map for ">=" instead of "==" as:
`inoremap <expr> > getline(".")[col(".")-3] == '>' ? "<bs>> " : getline(".")[col(".")-2] =~ '\s' ? "> " : ">"` which is giving me "> ="

Comment: The first `==` is a strict comparison. If  you want to do more complex analysis, you'd better use a function. Maintaining a one-liner made of multiple ternary operators, is quite complex. 

The idea is that the first test handle the special case and the second test handle the "there is a space before" case.

Comment: Regarding your second question, you'll have to fix `=` mapping to handle the case there is a `<` before